# How to resume baking fluid simulation?

Tags: fluid-simulation, baking

It happens sometimes that after finishing `bake` (e.g., for fluid simulation) we wish we could continue the simulation for two more seconds :(

**How to use the cached bake to continue the simulation?**

We played with the settings, but with no success.

[image]

Comment: I'm in the same situation. Now, I change the viewport to "final" to check the last few frames because the resolution can greatly affect the state of the fluid.

Answer (score 3):

The domain simulation of doing bake can't be resumed, it always starts from 0. Offset is for holding or use the cached animation later.

Comment: That's not the answer we want to hear.

Answer (score 0):

This answer refers to my experience with smoke simulation, I can't say if it applies to others:

- First, be sure to have your actual simulation cache loaded
- Go to the last calculated frame in your scene
- Press Ctrl+A to play the animation. Blender will then increment your cache and extend the simulation frame by frame
- Press Ctrl+A again to stop both playing and simulation