# Crashed fluid simulation

Tags: fluid-simulation

I've been baking a fluid simulation for the past four hours, and I decided to set up the materials in my scene while I was waiting.  While doing the materials, blender crashed.  Is there anyway that I can resume the baking right where it left off?  Thanks!  (This is seperate from [How to resume baking fluid simulation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5700/how-to-resume-baking-fluid-simulation)).

Comment: How is it different? Looks like more or less the same situation to me..

Comment: @gandalf3 So it's impossible to do any sort of resuming?

Comment: Yes (unfortunately).

Comment: I had Mantaflow baking a 750 res animation for 4 days, and right at frame 230 the power went out :(