# Workaround for Resuming Fluid Simulation

Tags: baking, fluid-simulation

Suppose I have a fluid simulation I have just baked and want another second of it.

Are there any drawbacks to applying the fluid simulation to the mesh (in the modifiers tab) then having that new mesh act as a fluid?

Both the answerers at [Is it possible to pause and later resume a fluid sim bake?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39259/is-it-possible-to-pause-and-later-resume-a-fluid-sim-bake) and [How to resume baking fluid simulation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5700/how-to-resume-baking-fluid-simulation) say it is not possible to resume a fluid simulation.

**EDIT**: The only drawback I can think of is the velocity it is moving at. However, that means that both stationary fluid and fluid moving in  a single direction can be resumed (there is a setting to set initial velocity)

**EDIT 2**: Now that I think about it, it is possible to split a single mesh into multiple smaller meshes. This way it is possible to set a different initial velocity for all the fluid parts.

Answer (score 0):

In Blender version 2.81+ now Mantaflow fluid and fire simulator is used which gives you the option to pause and resume fluid and fire bakes.